# Newton method with approximate Hessian? Choose a descent direction if only know the eiegnvalues of the hessian

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, computational-mathematics, newton-raphson, hessian-matrix

The question I am struggling with is ***'Suppose that it is easy to compute the eigenvalues of the Hessian of f. Briefly describe an alternative way to compute a suitable matrix $\boldsymbol{B}_{k}$. '***

--

The overall optimization problem is as follows

$$
\min _{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} f(\boldsymbol{x})
$$
Where $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a twice continuously differentiable function. The problem is a Newton method variant.

The descent direction $\Delta \boldsymbol{x}_{k}=-{\boldsymbol{B}_{k}}^{-1}\nabla \boldsymbol{f}\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{k}\right)$.

Update: Determine a scalar step size $t_{k}>0$ and update the solution,

$
\boldsymbol{x}_{k+1}=\boldsymbol{x}_{k}+t_{k} \Delta \boldsymbol{x}_{k}
$

$
\boldsymbol{B}_{k}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\nabla^{2} f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{k}\right) & \text { if } \nabla^{2} f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{k}\right) is\ positive \ definite\\
\boldsymbol{I} & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$

--

Now f(x) is not necessarily convex, I guess, but the ${B}_{k}$ chosen above ensures the descent direction is negative. Now I'm unsure what the question wants.

My thinking is to guess

$
\boldsymbol{B}_{k}$ = $diag(\lambda_{i})$ if all $\lambda_{i}$ are positive. Else the identity. As this is the original, as you still know exactly when the Hessian is positive definite. So $
{\boldsymbol{B}_{k}}^{-1}$ = $\Sigma^{-1}$ instead of $U\Sigma^{-1} U^{T}$

But I don't know really why, as U is orthonormal and you just know the eigenvalues not what eigenvector it corresponds to. So you are essentially just randomly scaling the maximal descent direction.

Can anyone help me? and clear up what's going on.

Comment: Other background in the previous parts of the question: $
f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{k}+t_{k} \Delta \boldsymbol{x}_{k}\right)-f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{k}\right) \leq t_{k}\left\langle\nabla f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{k}\right), \Delta \boldsymbol{x}_{k}\right\rangle+\frac{M}{2} t_{k}^{2}\left\|\Delta \boldsymbol{x}_{k}\right\|^{2}$

Where $M>0$ is a scalar. I'm not sure exactly why this is true. But something to do with the second order term being positive and third order negative.

Comment: Given $\Delta \boldsymbol{x}_{k},$ let $\alpha \in(0,0.5), \beta \in(0,1)$ and suppose that $t_{k}$ is chosen according to the following step size strategy:
While $f\left(x_{k}+t_{k} \Delta x_{k}\right)>f\left(x_{k}\right)+\alpha t_{k}\left\langle\nabla f\left(x_{k}\right), \Delta x_{k}\right\rangle$ set $t_{k}$ to $\beta t_{k}$

Comment: what does "suitable" mean here? is there some particular bound or theoretical guarantee that they want you to show? In other words, what would make a randomly-generated B "unsuitable"?

Comment: Yh I agree it is a bit vague. But I think just a B that allows convergence. That means the descent direction is still negative.